# ActiveRecord: Choose results based on value of a field in another model with a belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
Tracker belongs_to Property
Property belongs_to Branch
```

I am trying to efficiently do something like this:

Get all trackers where the branch's ID is 0 or 1. Tracker knows nothing about Branch except through Property.

Is it possible to form some sort of "where" statement that could get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use intermediate relation `Property` or you need to define new relation between `Tracker` and `Branch`

```
Tracker.joins(:property).merge(Property.where(branch_id: [0,1]))
```